# Owl Carousel jquery plugin autoHeight: true has no effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I am attempting to use the autoHeight feature in Owl Carousel 2 - which I have created an example CodePen of here:

[Example](http://codepen.io/LigCreative/pen/zrjqjg?editors=0100)

When you view the markup through inspector tools, you can see that the `.owl-height` elements height is indeed being updated, but the child elements are effecting the overall height.

I tried updating the `.owl-stage` to be `position: absolute;` - but it had other problematic effects, and I'm trying not to alter the original plugin files at all if possible... especially since it's a built in feature.

Is there something obvious I'm missing in using the autoHeight feature? The plugin appears to be included with Owl, but I could be missing something.

[Owl AutoHeight Documentation](http://smashingboxes.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoheight.html) in case it helps!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing some of the CSS for the navigation.

Turning the navigation off fixes the issue ([demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLjKGW?editors=0110)):

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    nav: false,
    items: 1,
    margin: 20,
    dots: true,
    autoHeight: true
});
```

Alternatively, check that you have included the `owl-theme.scss` file from [GitHub](https://github.com/smashingboxes/OwlCarousel2/blob/a13845c0d2275ce6d3174454bf50f5bb19f5af03/src/scss/_theme.scss). (Or you could style it yourself of course.)